# How to delete a remote branch using magit in emacs

Tags: git, emacs, magit

what is the magit key sequence which is the equivalent of

```
git push origin :branch-to-be-deleted
```

that will cause the branch to be dropped from the remote repo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The built in branch delete feature of magit (`magit-status`, `b` `k`; or directly call the function `magit-branch-delete`) will delete remote branches in addition to local branches. Instead of specifying `my-branch` as the branch to delete, make sure to specify `my-remote/my-branch`.

Comment: Note that branch deletion is bound to `magit-status`,`b`,`x` (instead of `k`) in the current version of Magit.

Answer (score 23):

You can type <kbd>y</kbd> (`magit-show-refs`) to go to the refs buffer, and then <kbd>k</kbd> (`magit-branch-delete`) on any remote branch to delete it.

Comment: For me that was `y r`

Comment: For me, it was `x` rather than `k`.

Comment: I'll just note that neither `x` nor `r` are standard Magit key bindings for this.  By default `x` is for resetting, and `r` is for rebasing, and `k` is for discarding or deleting.  Anything different is due to your own config.  Thanks for adding the command names to the answer, @Mark.

Comment: those alternative keybindings are default when using evil and evil-collection packages, fwiw. See https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/blob/master/modes/magit/evil-collection-magit.el